# Web scraping a table with BeautifulSoup and the output has the column names multiple times

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to BeautifulSoup and to programming in general, and I'm having trouble when scraping data from a table. When I convert it into a DataFrame the output is displaying the column names multiple times and I'm not sure how to remove them. When I tried to reshape the df it only allowed me to reshape five rows at a time instead of all of them and I'm not sure why.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
odds_url = "https://www.oddsshark.com/mlb/extended-standings"
r = requests.get(odds_url)
        
standings_soup = bs(r_.content, 'html.parser')
    
tables = standings_soup.find_all('div', {"class":"table-wrapper"})
   for tables in tables:
      column_names =[th.getText() for th in tables.findAll('tr')[0].findAll('th')][0:10]
      trow_data = [td.getText() for td in tables.findAll('td')]
      standings_df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(trow_data,(5,10)))
      standings_df.columns = column_names
      standings_df = standings_df
      print(standings_df)
```

The output of the DataFrame looks like this.

```
            Team Record League Division   Home   Away vs LHP vs RHP       %  \
0      Minnesota  48-40  45-35    22-16  25-18  23-22  14-10  34-30  0.5455   
1      Cleveland  41-42  33-35    18-17  20-17  21-25  15-12  26-30  0.4940   
2  Chi White Sox  41-43  34-40    13-16  19-25  22-18   7-10  34-33  0.4881   
3        Detroit  36-49  28-42    18-18  22-24  14-25  10-14  26-35  0.4235   
4    Kansas City  32-52  28-44    15-19  16-26  16-26  11-14  21-38  0.3810   

  Games Back  
0          -  
1        4.5  
2          5  
3       10.5  
4         14  
         Team Record League Division   Home   Away vs LHP vs RHP       %  \
0  NY Yankees  61-25  57-24    28-14   34-9  27-16   19-8  42-17  0.7093   
1      Boston  47-39  42-34    11-20  23-20  24-19   15-6  32-33  0.5465   
2   Tampa Bay  45-40  35-34    17-16  25-17  20-23  10-12  35-28  0.5294   
3     Toronto  45-42  41-38    16-18  25-18  20-24   7-11  38-31  0.5172   
4   Baltimore  43-44  38-40    15-19  25-17  18-27  17-14  26-30  0.4943   

  Games Back  
0          -  
1         14  
2       15.5  
3       16.5  
4       18.5
```

These are the tables I'm trying to scrape for reference.

```
<caption>American League Central</caption>
<thead><tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 122px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr></thead>
<tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 122px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr>
<th style="position: absolute; width: 122px;">Team</th>
<th>Record</th>
<th>League</th>
<th>Division</th>
<th>Home</th>
<th>Away</th>
<th>vs LHP</th>
<th>vs RHP</th>
<th>%</th>
<th>Games Back</th>
<tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 122px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr>
<thead><tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 122px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27005">Minnesota</a></td><td class="td ">38-30</td><td class="td ">37-26</td><td class="td ">17-10</td><td class="td ">20-14</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">25-21</td><td class="td ">0.5588</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27024">Cleveland</a></td><td class="td ">34-28</td><td class="td ">26-21</td><td class="td ">12-8</td><td class="td ">16-10</td><td class="td ">18-18</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">21-19</td><td class="td ">0.5484</td><td class="td ">1</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27018">Chi White Sox</a></td><td class="td ">31-33</td><td class="td ">27-30</td><td class="td ">10-12</td><td class="td ">13-17</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">7-9</td><td class="td ">24-24</td><td class="td ">0.4844</td><td class="td ">5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/26999">Detroit</a></td><td class="td ">26-40</td><td class="td ">21-35</td><td class="td ">11-14</td><td class="td ">17-22</td><td class="td ">9-18</td><td class="td ">7-11</td><td class="td ">19-29</td><td class="td ">0.3939</td><td class="td ">11</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27006">Kansas City</a></td><td class="td ">23-42</td><td class="td ">19-34</td><td class="td ">11-17</td><td class="td ">12-21</td><td class="td ">11-21</td><td class="td ">8-12</td><td class="td ">15-30</td><td class="td ">0.3538</td><td class="td ">13.5</td></tr></tbody>
<tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27005">Minnesota</a></td><td class="td ">38-30</td><td class="td ">37-26</td><td class="td ">17-10</td><td class="td ">20-14</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">25-21</td><td class="td ">0.5588</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr>
<td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27005">Minnesota</a></td>
<td class="td ">38-30</td>
<td class="td ">37-26</td>
<td class="td ">17-10</td>
<td class="td ">20-14</td>
<td class="td ">18-16</td>
<td class="td ">13-9</td>
<td class="td ">25-21</td>
<td class="td ">0.5588</td>
<td class="td ">-</td>
<tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27005">Minnesota</a></td><td class="td ">38-30</td><td class="td ">37-26</td><td class="td ">17-10</td><td class="td ">20-14</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">25-21</td><td class="td ">0.5588</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr>
<tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27024">Cleveland</a></td><td class="td ">34-28</td><td class="td ">26-21</td><td class="td ">12-8</td><td class="td ">16-10</td><td class="td ">18-18</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">21-19</td><td class="td ">0.5484</td><td class="td ">1</td></tr>
<tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27018">Chi White Sox</a></td><td class="td ">31-33</td><td class="td ">27-30</td><td class="td ">10-12</td><td class="td ">13-17</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">7-9</td><td class="td ">24-24</td><td class="td ">0.4844</td><td class="td ">5</td></tr>
<tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/26999">Detroit</a></td><td class="td ">26-40</td><td class="td ">21-35</td><td class="td ">11-14</td><td class="td ">17-22</td><td class="td ">9-18</td><td class="td ">7-11</td><td class="td ">19-29</td><td class="td ">0.3939</td><td class="td ">11</td></tr>
<tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27006">Kansas City</a></td><td class="td ">23-42</td><td class="td ">19-34</td><td class="td ">11-17</td><td class="td ">12-21</td><td class="td ">11-21</td><td class="td ">8-12</td><td class="td ">15-30</td><td class="td ">0.3538</td><td class="td ">13.5</td></tr>
<tbody><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27005">Minnesota</a></td><td class="td ">38-30</td><td class="td ">37-26</td><td class="td ">17-10</td><td class="td ">20-14</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">25-21</td><td class="td ">0.5588</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27024">Cleveland</a></td><td class="td ">34-28</td><td class="td ">26-21</td><td class="td ">12-8</td><td class="td ">16-10</td><td class="td ">18-18</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">21-19</td><td class="td ">0.5484</td><td class="td ">1</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27018">Chi White Sox</a></td><td class="td ">31-33</td><td class="td ">27-30</td><td class="td ">10-12</td><td class="td ">13-17</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">7-9</td><td class="td ">24-24</td><td class="td ">0.4844</td><td class="td ">5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/26999">Detroit</a></td><td class="td ">26-40</td><td class="td ">21-35</td><td class="td ">11-14</td><td class="td ">17-22</td><td class="td ">9-18</td><td class="td ">7-11</td><td class="td ">19-29</td><td class="td ">0.3939</td><td class="td ">11</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27006">Kansas City</a></td><td class="td ">23-42</td><td class="td ">19-34</td><td class="td ">11-17</td><td class="td ">12-21</td><td class="td ">11-21</td><td class="td ">8-12</td><td class="td ">15-30</td><td class="td ">0.3538</td><td class="td ">13.5</td></tr></tbody>
<table class="table table table--striped table--fixed-column" style="padding-left: 122px;"><caption>American League Central</caption><thead><tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 122px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27005">Minnesota</a></td><td class="td ">38-30</td><td class="td ">37-26</td><td class="td ">17-10</td><td class="td ">20-14</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">25-21</td><td class="td ">0.5588</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27024">Cleveland</a></td><td class="td ">34-28</td><td class="td ">26-21</td><td class="td ">12-8</td><td class="td ">16-10</td><td class="td ">18-18</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">21-19</td><td class="td ">0.5484</td><td class="td ">1</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27018">Chi White Sox</a></td><td class="td ">31-33</td><td class="td ">27-30</td><td class="td ">10-12</td><td class="td ">13-17</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">7-9</td><td class="td ">24-24</td><td class="td ">0.4844</td><td class="td ">5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/26999">Detroit</a></td><td class="td ">26-40</td><td class="td ">21-35</td><td class="td ">11-14</td><td class="td ">17-22</td><td class="td ">9-18</td><td class="td ">7-11</td><td class="td ">19-29</td><td class="td ">0.3939</td><td class="td ">11</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27006">Kansas City</a></td><td class="td ">23-42</td><td class="td ">19-34</td><td class="td ">11-17</td><td class="td ">12-21</td><td class="td ">11-21</td><td class="td ">8-12</td><td class="td ">15-30</td><td class="td ">0.3538</td><td class="td ">13.5</td></tr></tbody></table>
<<pseudo>></<pseudo>>
<div class="table-wrapper__overflow" style="padding-top: 60px;"><table class="table table table--striped table--fixed-column" style="padding-left: 122px;"><caption>American League Central</caption><thead><tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 122px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27005">Minnesota</a></td><td class="td ">38-30</td><td class="td ">37-26</td><td class="td ">17-10</td><td class="td ">20-14</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">25-21</td><td class="td ">0.5588</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27024">Cleveland</a></td><td class="td ">34-28</td><td class="td ">26-21</td><td class="td ">12-8</td><td class="td ">16-10</td><td class="td ">18-18</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">21-19</td><td class="td ">0.5484</td><td class="td ">1</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27018">Chi White Sox</a></td><td class="td ">31-33</td><td class="td ">27-30</td><td class="td ">10-12</td><td class="td ">13-17</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">7-9</td><td class="td ">24-24</td><td class="td ">0.4844</td><td class="td ">5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/26999">Detroit</a></td><td class="td ">26-40</td><td class="td ">21-35</td><td class="td ">11-14</td><td class="td ">17-22</td><td class="td ">9-18</td><td class="td ">7-11</td><td class="td ">19-29</td><td class="td ">0.3939</td><td class="td ">11</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27006">Kansas City</a></td><td class="td ">23-42</td><td class="td ">19-34</td><td class="td ">11-17</td><td class="td ">12-21</td><td class="td ">11-21</td><td class="td ">8-12</td><td class="td ">15-30</td><td class="td ">0.3538</td><td class="td ">13.5</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
<div class="table-wrapper " data-once="os-tables"><div class="table-wrapper__overflow" style="padding-top: 60px;"><table class="table table table--striped table--fixed-column" style="padding-left: 122px;"><caption>American League Central</caption><thead><tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 122px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27005">Minnesota</a></td><td class="td ">38-30</td><td class="td ">37-26</td><td class="td ">17-10</td><td class="td ">20-14</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">25-21</td><td class="td ">0.5588</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27024">Cleveland</a></td><td class="td ">34-28</td><td class="td ">26-21</td><td class="td ">12-8</td><td class="td ">16-10</td><td class="td ">18-18</td><td class="td ">13-9</td><td class="td ">21-19</td><td class="td ">0.5484</td><td class="td ">1</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27018">Chi White Sox</a></td><td class="td ">31-33</td><td class="td ">27-30</td><td class="td ">10-12</td><td class="td ">13-17</td><td class="td ">18-16</td><td class="td ">7-9</td><td class="td ">24-24</td><td class="td ">0.4844</td><td class="td ">5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/26999">Detroit</a></td><td class="td ">26-40</td><td class="td ">21-35</td><td class="td ">11-14</td><td class="td ">17-22</td><td class="td ">9-18</td><td class="td ">7-11</td><td class="td ">19-29</td><td class="td ">0.3939</td><td class="td ">11</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 122px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27006">Kansas City</a></td><td class="td ">23-42</td><td class="td ">19-34</td><td class="td ">11-17</td><td class="td ">12-21</td><td class="td ">11-21</td><td class="td ">8-12</td><td class="td ">15-30</td><td class="td ">0.3538</td><td class="td ">13.5</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
<div class="table-wrapper " data-once="os-tables"><div class="table-wrapper__overflow" style="padding-top: 60px;"><table class="table table table--striped table--fixed-column" style="padding-left: 109px;"><caption>American League East</caption><thead><tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 109px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 109px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27001">NY Yankees</a></td><td class="td ">49-17</td><td class="td ">46-17</td><td class="td ">24-11</td><td class="td ">29-7</td><td class="td ">20-10</td><td class="td ">15-6</td><td class="td ">34-11</td><td class="td ">0.7424</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 109px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27010">Toronto</a></td><td class="td ">38-28</td><td class="td ">35-26</td><td class="td ">12-14</td><td class="td ">21-14</td><td class="td ">17-14</td><td class="td ">7-7</td><td class="td ">31-21</td><td class="td ">0.5758</td><td class="td ">11</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 109px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27003">Tampa Bay</a></td><td class="td ">36-30</td><td class="td ">29-29</td><td class="td ">11-11</td><td class="td ">21-13</td><td class="td ">15-17</td><td class="td ">9-7</td><td class="td ">27-23</td><td class="td ">0.5455</td><td class="td ">13</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 109px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27021">Boston</a></td><td class="td ">36-31</td><td class="td ">32-28</td><td class="td ">7-14</td><td class="td ">17-16</td><td class="td ">19-15</td><td class="td ">12-4</td><td class="td ">24-27</td><td class="td ">0.5373</td><td class="td ">13.5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 109px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27008">Baltimore</a></td><td class="td ">30-38</td><td class="td ">26-35</td><td class="td ">15-19</td><td class="td ">17-16</td><td class="td ">13-22</td><td class="td ">12-13</td><td class="td ">18-25</td><td class="td ">0.4412</td><td class="td ">20</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
<div class="table-wrapper " data-once="os-tables"><div class="table-wrapper__overflow" style="padding-top: 60px;"><table class="table table table--striped table--fixed-column" style="padding-left: 97px;"><caption>American League West</caption><thead><tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 97px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 97px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27023">Houston</a></td><td class="td ">41-25</td><td class="td ">37-21</td><td class="td ">21-12</td><td class="td ">18-11</td><td class="td ">23-14</td><td class="td ">14-7</td><td class="td ">27-18</td><td class="td ">0.6212</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 97px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/26998">LA Angels</a></td><td class="td ">33-36</td><td class="td ">28-28</td><td class="td ">16-12</td><td class="td ">17-18</td><td class="td ">16-18</td><td class="td ">8-10</td><td class="td ">25-26</td><td class="td ">0.4783</td><td class="td ">9.5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 97px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27002">Texas</a></td><td class="td ">31-35</td><td class="td ">27-32</td><td class="td ">15-18</td><td class="td ">14-18</td><td class="td ">17-17</td><td class="td ">15-10</td><td class="td ">16-25</td><td class="td ">0.4697</td><td class="td ">10</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 97px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27011">Seattle</a></td><td class="td ">29-39</td><td class="td ">25-34</td><td class="td ">12-14</td><td class="td ">15-18</td><td class="td ">14-21</td><td class="td ">4-13</td><td class="td ">25-26</td><td class="td ">0.4265</td><td class="td ">13</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 97px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27016">Oakland</a></td><td class="td ">23-45</td><td class="td ">21-40</td><td class="td ">6-14</td><td class="td ">8-26</td><td class="td ">15-19</td><td class="td ">8-13</td><td class="td ">15-32</td><td class="td ">0.3382</td><td class="td ">19</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
<div class="table-wrapper " data-once="os-tables"><div class="table-wrapper__overflow" style="padding-top: 60px;"><table class="table table table--striped table--fixed-column" style="padding-left: 100px;"><caption>National League Central</caption><thead><tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 100px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 100px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27012">Milwaukee</a></td><td class="td ">38-30</td><td class="td ">36-29</td><td class="td ">22-11</td><td class="td ">15-12</td><td class="td ">23-18</td><td class="td ">11-13</td><td class="td ">27-17</td><td class="td ">0.5588</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 100px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27019">St. Louis</a></td><td class="td ">38-30</td><td class="td ">32-21</td><td class="td ">19-10</td><td class="td ">21-13</td><td class="td ">17-17</td><td class="td ">7-6</td><td class="td ">31-24</td><td class="td ">0.5588</td><td class="td ">0</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 100px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27013">Pittsburgh</a></td><td class="td ">26-39</td><td class="td ">25-36</td><td class="td ">10-22</td><td class="td ">14-19</td><td class="td ">12-20</td><td class="td ">9-15</td><td class="td ">17-24</td><td class="td ">0.4000</td><td class="td ">10.5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 100px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27020">Chi Cubs</a></td><td class="td ">25-41</td><td class="td ">23-32</td><td class="td ">13-15</td><td class="td ">13-25</td><td class="td ">12-16</td><td class="td ">8-11</td><td class="td ">17-30</td><td class="td ">0.3788</td><td class="td ">12</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 100px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27000">Cincinnati</a></td><td class="td ">23-43</td><td class="td ">19-38</td><td class="td ">10-16</td><td class="td ">12-20</td><td class="td ">11-23</td><td class="td ">7-12</td><td class="td ">16-31</td><td class="td ">0.3485</td><td class="td ">14</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
<div class="table-wrapper " data-once="os-tables"><div class="table-wrapper__overflow" style="padding-top: 60px;"><table class="table table table--striped table--fixed-column" style="padding-left: 110px;"><caption>National League East</caption><thead><tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 110px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 110px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27014">NY Mets</a></td><td class="td ">44-24</td><td class="td ">41-21</td><td class="td ">21-8</td><td class="td ">23-10</td><td class="td ">21-14</td><td class="td ">14-10</td><td class="td ">30-14</td><td class="td ">0.6471</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 110px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27009">Atlanta</a></td><td class="td ">38-29</td><td class="td ">34-26</td><td class="td ">13-10</td><td class="td ">20-14</td><td class="td ">18-15</td><td class="td ">16-7</td><td class="td ">22-22</td><td class="td ">0.5672</td><td class="td ">5.5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 110px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/26995">Philadelphia</a></td><td class="td ">36-32</td><td class="td ">29-28</td><td class="td ">12-16</td><td class="td ">19-17</td><td class="td ">17-15</td><td class="td ">13-8</td><td class="td ">23-24</td><td class="td ">0.5294</td><td class="td ">8</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 110px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27022">Miami</a></td><td class="td ">29-35</td><td class="td ">25-29</td><td class="td ">17-11</td><td class="td ">15-14</td><td class="td ">14-21</td><td class="td ">8-6</td><td class="td ">21-29</td><td class="td ">0.4531</td><td class="td ">13</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 110px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27017">Washington</a></td><td class="td ">24-46</td><td class="td ">22-42</td><td class="td ">6-24</td><td class="td ">12-26</td><td class="td ">12-20</td><td class="td ">10-15</td><td class="td ">14-31</td><td class="td ">0.3429</td><td class="td ">21</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
<div class="table-wrapper " data-once="os-tables"><div class="table-wrapper__overflow" style="padding-top: 60px;"><table class="table table table--striped table--fixed-column" style="padding-left: 123px;"><caption>National League West</caption><thead><tr><th style="position: absolute; width: 123px;">Team</th><th>Record</th><th>League</th><th>Division</th><th>Home</th><th>Away</th><th>vs LHP</th><th>vs RHP</th><th>%</th><th>Games Back</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 123px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27015">LA Dodgers</a></td><td class="td ">40-25</td><td class="td ">31-21</td><td class="td ">14-8</td><td class="td ">20-12</td><td class="td ">20-13</td><td class="td ">14-8</td><td class="td ">26-17</td><td class="td ">0.6154</td><td class="td ">-</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 123px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/26996">San Diego</a></td><td class="td ">41-27</td><td class="td ">40-26</td><td class="td ">10-10</td><td class="td ">17-13</td><td class="td ">24-14</td><td class="td ">16-7</td><td class="td ">25-20</td><td class="td ">0.6029</td><td class="td ">0.5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 123px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/26997">San Francisco</a></td><td class="td ">37-28</td><td class="td ">31-26</td><td class="td ">11-9</td><td class="td ">19-14</td><td class="td ">18-14</td><td class="td ">13-6</td><td class="td ">24-22</td><td class="td ">0.5692</td><td class="td ">3</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 123px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27007">Arizona</a></td><td class="td ">32-36</td><td class="td ">27-34</td><td class="td ">5-13</td><td class="td ">17-19</td><td class="td ">15-17</td><td class="td ">10-9</td><td class="td ">22-27</td><td class="td ">0.4706</td><td class="td ">9.5</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="td " style="position: absolute; width: 123px;"><a href="https://www.oddsshark.com/stats/team/baseball/mlb/27004">Colorado</a></td><td class="td ">30-37</td><td class="td ">25-31</td><td class="td ">11-11</td><td class="td ">19-19</td><td class="td ">11-18</td><td class="td ">12-12</td><td class="td ">18-25</td><td class="td ">0.4478</td><td class="td ">11</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
```

This is my first official post.
Any tips or constructive criticism to ask better questions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get all the different tables into one single dataframe? It looks like your code is formatting the tables properly but you are generating a separate dataframe for each table from the website with the same columns, so you end up printing out each table with the same columns over and over. IIUC you are trying to get it so that the "Team Record League Division   Home   Away vs LHP vs RHP..." doesn't get printed over and over.

One way to solving this is by merging each dataframe for each separate table into one using [.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
odds_url = "https://www.oddsshark.com/mlb/extended-standings"
r = requests.get(odds_url)
        
standings_soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
    
tables = standings_soup.find_all('div', {"class":"table-wrapper"})
dfs = []
for tables in tables:
    column_names =[th.getText() for th in tables.findAll('tr')[0].findAll('th')][0:10]
    trow_data = [td.getText() for td in tables.findAll('td')]
    standings_df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(trow_data,(5,10)))
    standings_df.columns = column_names
    dfs.append(standings_df)

merged_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
print(merged_df)
```

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Comment: Yea I want to create a single DataFrame without printing the columns names over and over. Thank you @jp207 , this did the trick.  Thanks @ hedgeHog I did not know I was using old syntax. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is a wonderful tool to parse html. So much in fact that `pandas` uses it under the hood to parse `<table>` tags.

Let pandas do the work here since what you are after are within `<table>` tags. `pandas` will return all `<table>` tags into a list of dataframes. Then it's just a matter of combining them.

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.oddsshark.com/mlb/extended-standings')
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
            Team Record League Division  ... vs LHP vs RHP       % Games Back
0      Minnesota  48-41  45-35    22-16  ...  14-10  34-31  0.5393          -
1      Cleveland  43-43  35-36    20-18  ...  15-12  28-31  0.5000        3.5
2  Chi White Sox  42-45  35-42    14-18  ...   8-10  34-35  0.4828          5
3        Detroit  37-51  29-44    19-20  ...  11-15  26-36  0.4205       10.5
4    Kansas City  34-53  30-45    17-20  ...  11-14  23-39  0.3908         13
0     NY Yankees  61-26  57-24    28-14  ...   19-8  42-18  0.7011          -
1      Tampa Bay  47-40  37-34    19-16  ...  11-12  36-28  0.5402         14
2         Boston  47-41  42-36    11-22  ...   15-6  32-35  0.5341       14.5
3        Toronto  46-42  41-38    16-18  ...   7-11  39-31  0.5227       15.5
4      Baltimore  44-44  38-40    15-19  ...  17-14  27-30  0.5000       17.5
0        Houston  57-29  49-25    27-13  ...   18-9  39-20  0.6628          -
1        Seattle  45-42  39-37    20-16  ...   7-13  38-29  0.5172       12.5
2          Texas  40-45  32-38    16-19  ...  17-11  23-34  0.4706       16.5
3      LA Angels  38-50  32-41    17-18  ...  11-12  27-38  0.4318         20
4        Oakland  30-59  28-54     9-23  ...  11-18  19-41  0.3371       28.5
0      Milwaukee  49-39  42-37    28-19  ...  14-14  35-25  0.5568          -
1      St. Louis  48-42  42-33    22-14  ...    9-8  39-34  0.5333          2
2     Pittsburgh  38-50  36-43    18-27  ...  15-19  23-31  0.4318         11
3       Chi Cubs  34-53  30-42    20-21  ...   9-16  25-37  0.3908       14.5
4     Cincinnati  33-54  25-49    12-19  ...   8-17  25-37  0.3793       15.5
0        NY Mets  54-34  49-26    27-12  ...  19-14  35-20  0.6136          -
1        Atlanta  53-36  49-33    19-12  ...   22-9  31-27  0.5955        1.5
2   Philadelphia  46-42  39-35    15-19  ...  14-11  32-31  0.5227          8
3          Miami  41-45  36-38    24-16  ...   11-7  30-38  0.4767         12
4     Washington  30-58  25-52     7-33  ...  11-21  19-37  0.3409         24
0     LA Dodgers  56-30  47-26    21-11  ...  17-11  39-19  0.6512          -
1      San Diego  50-39  49-36    18-17  ...  20-12  30-27  0.5618        7.5
2  San Francisco  44-42  37-36    15-14  ...  17-10  27-32  0.5116         12
3       Colorado  39-49  33-41    19-18  ...  17-18  22-31  0.4432         18
4        Arizona  39-49  33-45    11-24  ...  14-12  25-37  0.4432         18

[30 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Wow I did not know it can be done so easily. Thank you so much @chitown88 that saved me so many lines of code!